# Is it possible to combine SYSTEMJS with REQUIREJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, systemjs

I'd like to attach my app to an existing portal app which uses REQUIREJS as amd loader. I would extend this app, but I would like to go for SYSTEMJS's loader with my part. It doesn't seem to be possible to use modules in the systemjs context, which were loaded with requirejs.

I have prepared a plunkr example for my problem:

```
  requirejs(['AlternateCase.js'], function(AlternateCase) {
    console.log(AlternateCase);
    System.import("app.js");
  });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/nRnnHzRLyTJCT826WBo4

AlternateCase is an angular filter which I load with requirejs - the app I load using systemjs. I get the filter object (console.log) but I get "unknown provider" in my app for the filter.

The challenge is that ***the code of the filter must not be changed***, because it represents the exsting app which I want to load but which I cannot change.

Comment: `app.js` isn't exporting anything, so trying to require it would return nothing. Look into [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) for libraries and files that do not call `define`

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, but I would like to import the filter object into app.js - not the other way round. Thanks

Comment: my bad I totally misread the question - is AlternateCase exporting anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to create a Plunker which works. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/a3ZMek8aUmBuusoIFBjE?p=preview

I have also accomplished to alternatively use system.js for AMD loading by overwriting requirejs with System.amdRequire.

```
window.requirejs = System.amdRequire;
```

However, requirejs + systemjs combines well too.